# Angular - Elements that are under ngIf* doesn't render when ngOnInit() is called

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if, ngoninit

I notice that when I have some elements under ngIf*, on ngOnInit() those elements don't exists even when the condition is met. How can I "catch" the moment when an element that is under ngIf* is rendered (I need to call some function on it)

Comment: you can use `afterViewInit` and read more about life cycle here https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

use `ngAfterViewInit()`

ngAfterViewInit() is called after a component's view, and its children's views, are created. Its a lifecycle hook that is called after a component's view has been fully initialized.

```
export class AfterViewInitDemoComponent implements AfterViewInit { 
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("---ngAfterViewInit() Demo---");
  }
}
```

please check following links for more info

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-ngafterviewinit

Answer (score 0):

If you use @ViewChild, try to use `static: true` parameter.

`@ViewChild('myElem', { static: true }) myElem: MyElementType;`